# Can cron "cache" scripts it runs?

Tags: shell-script, cron, cache, perl

Caveats up front:
1. My *nix knowledge is very limited but growing.
2. This particular issue applies to SunOS 5.10 (I know) but I'd be interested in general answers.

If a cron entry runs script `myscript.pl` every minute and at some point I modify that script file, is the next cron execution *guaranteed* to execute the changed script, or could it somewhere/somehow have a cached version which it would continue to execute?

I guess the Perl interpreter may also come into this particular issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll run the new version, as each time cron runs, it will repeat the commands it has cached from the crontab, but not the 'result' of those commands.

So, if you've changed the script, but not the actual crontab itself, it'll run the new script, each time.

If you've changed the crontab (i.e. maybe how often it runs, the path to the script etc) then you must call `crontab` to have it re-read this infomation. Otherwise cron checks for changes via the modtime, or using ionotify, as from the man page:

> ```
>    There are two ways how changes in crontables are checked.  The first
>    method is checking the modtime of a file.  The second method is using
>    the inotify support.  Using of inotify is logged in the /var/log/cron
>    log after the daemon is started.  The inotify support checks for
>    changes in all crontables and accesses the hard disk only when a
>    change is detected.
>
>    When using the modtime option, Cron checks its crontables' modtimes
>    every minute to check for any changes and reloads the crontables
>    which have changed.  There is no need to restart Cron after some of
>    the crontables were modified.  The modtime option is also used when
>    inotify can not be initialized.
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I figured that was likely the case, but just couldn't see it written clearly anywhere.